# How do I get mutt to send data over SMS?

Tags: email, mutt, sms

I'm trying to use mutt to send emails to ##########@vtext.com, effectively using mutt for SMS. Unfortunately all of the mail I've sent hasn't reached my phone.

I'm thinking that mutt needs some additional configuration in the muttrc file just like with sending messages with mutt to gmail.

This is just my number, but this process can easily be replicated on any phone number.

So what's going wrong with mutt?

Comment: I don't think anything is going wrong with mutt, I presume vtext is a service where they convert your email into a text message? The issue lies likely with them. Can mutt send emails anywhere else?

Comment: Mutt works locally, and emails from gmail are received as SMS messages on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed an issue with my setup for this same issue. 
vtext (and mms.cricketwireless.net too btw.) apparently block messages without a valid MX record, or some similar type of sanity/security check. 
Basically, my smtp server and my computer aren't the same and whatever vtext.com uses was aware of that and rejected this kind of behavior.

editing/adding the line 
myorigin = smtp.servername.suffix

in main.cf for postfix (for me was /etc/postfix/main.cf your's might be different) fixed this issue for me.

My understanding is that this told the sms from e-mail server that the message was valid. i.e. where it says it is coming from is equal to where it is actually coming from.

Other than that, you can systematically check other aspects of your mutt configuration (i.e. mutt -D), postfix configurations, or try to tell mutt to use something like imap/smtp servers from elsewhere (like imaps://imap.google.com).